# Numpy, multiply 3x3 array by 3x10 array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 3x10 matrix (in the form of a numpy array) and would like to multiply it by a 3x3 transformation matrix.  I don't think np.dot is doing the full matrix multiplication.  Is there a method for doing this multiplication with arrays?

```
transf = np.array([ [0.1, -0.4, 0],[0.9, 0.75, -0.1],[0.5, 0.75, -0.9] ])

one = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]
two = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10]
three = [2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11]

data = np.array([ one, two, three ])

new_data = np.dot(transf,data)
```

Is there a dot function that does the entire matrix multiplication, not just ["For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) states that for 2d arrays, `np.dot` is equivalent to matrix multiplication...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing commas in the last two entries of `transf`. Fix them and you'll get matrix multiplication as you'd expect:

```
# Missing commas between 0.75 and -0.1, 0.75 and -0.9.
transf = np.array([ [0.1, -0.4, 0],[0.9, 0.75 -0.1],[0.5, 0.75 -0.9] ])

# Fix with commas
transf = np.array([ [0.1, -0.4, 0],[0.9, 0.75, -0.1],[0.5, 0.75, -0.9]])
```

Because the first array is not actually a legitimate 2-D array, `np.dot` cannot perform matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply by `*` operator but you will need to define the `matrix` rather than `array`.

```
import numpy as np
transf = np.matrix([ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3] ])     # 3x3 matrix
data = np.matrix([[2], [3], [4] ])      # 3x1 matrix

print transf * data
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the matrix * is the same as the array dot.

Comment: And newer Python/numpys have a `@` operator that acts the same way.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you have a source for that? I didn't know that 
`@` worked as an operator in python

Comment: @KevinOrr  `@` is added in python3.5 (see [PEP 465](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) for details)...